# Pregmatch and Regex not working

Tags: php, regex

I have a quick shortcode for generating list.. below is how the shortcode looks..

```
 [mainlist]
   [listitem var1="" var2=""][/listitem]
   [listitem var1="" var2=""][/listitem]
   [listitem var1="" var2=""][/listitem]
   [listitem var1="" var2=""][/listitem]
 [/mainlist]
```

and another occurrence of the same code with different variable values..

```
 [mainlist]
   [listitem var1="" var2=""][/listitem]
   [listitem var1="" var2=""][/listitem]
 [/mainlist]
```

I am using the following code to find out the number of [listitem] within the main list..

```
 preg_match_all( '/(\[listitem (.*?)\](.*?)\[\/listitem\])/' , $content, $matches);

 if(is_array($matches) && !empty($matches))
   $total_items = count($matches[0]);
```

if I echo the result it shows me 4 and 0. It counts the first occurrence perfectly for the second one it simple shows 0, why is that and how can I improve this code.

thanks

Comment: Have you tried echoing `$content` to make sure it's looking at the right thing? Also, are all the values actually empty strings, or have you removed them? They might be relevant.

Comment: Hi Michele, thanks for the input, I think here is another problem after checking the $content.. the list doesn't come with wrapped [mainlist] so instead it comes with the first 4   [listitem var1="" var2=""][/listitem]

and then the second    [listitem var1="" var2=""][/listitem]
   [listitem var1="" var2=""][/listitem]

how can I assign a variable and differentiate that these are 2 different lists as there is no [mainlist], so it shows the first 4 as total and then 0 for the second occurrence..

Comment: It seems working fine for me. As said Michelle, show us the content of `$content`.

Comment: Can you add the code that assigns to `$content` to your post so that we can see how you're getting values for it?

Comment: Please find the code on jsfiddle HTML area.. http://jsfiddle.net/cpzt9/

Comment: Do you need to match everything?  Or just count the number of opening `listitem` tags?

Comment: Hi Rick, I just need the number of each mainlist.. cheers

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I tried to replicate your code, as best I could without having all of it, and it does seem to match what you are wanting it to.  Even without the `mainlist` tags.

```
$content = '
    [mainlist]
      [listitem var1="" var2=""][/listitem]
      [listitem var1="" var2=""][/listitem]
      [listitem var1="" var2=""][/listitem]
      [listitem var1="" var2=""][/listitem]
    [/mainlist]
      [listitem var1="" var2=""][/listitem]
      [listitem var1="" var2=""][/listitem]';


preg_match_all('/\[listitem(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/listitem\]/', $content, $matches);

print "<PRE><FONT COLOR=ORANGE>"; print_r($matches); print "</FONT></PRE>";

if(is_array($matches) && !empty($matches)) {
    $total_items = count($matches[0]);
}

// THIS PRINTS 6
print "<BR>TOTAL ITEMS: ".$total_items;
```

So that leads me to think that the problem is, as Michelle is suggesting, with your `mainlist` function pulling in the content.  Basically, I think the answer to your problem is not in the REGEX part as you are thinking, but in the part that builds out the list items to begin with.

Check to make sure that that `add_shortcode` function is constructing the `mainlist` items correctly.  Then the rest of your code should work.

Comment: The problem is it only returns for the first array, doesn't work if there are other similar shortscodes, it simply return 0.. i tried to reset array, use global variables, add another array of content, again its same, may be its issue with wordpress itself?

Comment: Okay, so is the problem with your function that's bringing the data back?  Or with your REGEX?  This is what I am confused on.  Your question is for REGEX, but that part seems to work fine.

Comment: Hi Rick, at first I thought it was my regex, but your code and mine are almost same, and both return the same result, I mean for the first time it shows correct number of total_items bu when the shortcode is found again on the same page, it returns 0 number of items, so I assume, both the above codes are fine, there is problem with do_shortcode() function..

Comment: The problem is fixed, the problem was I copied my shortcode fomr another page and pasted it, it add was like added like this

[listitem var1="blah blah
blah blah"]
[/listitem]

I dont know why the regex was not finding it, soon as I made it on one line it worked fine.. such a waste of 4 hours..

Comment: Oh, gotcha.  Okay, well you can probably use the `ms` pattern modifiers to search through multiple lines. `'/\[listitem(.*?)\](.*?)\[\/listitem\]/ms'`